# nft delegate confusion (metaplex token metadata)

Tags: anchor, rust, pda, metadata, cpi

I'm trying to delegate an pnft to a pda.

but I keep getting `incorrect account owner`.

I can't for the life of me know how the account owner is incorrect. and what the delegate field in the `DelegateUtilityV1CpiAccounts` should be since it's description says `Owner of the delegated account` yet isn't the owner the owner of the ata? then where would I input the account I want to delegate?

here is the code snippet:

```
       DelegateUtilityV1Cpi::new(
            &(accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info()),
            DelegateUtilityV1CpiAccounts { 
                delegate_record: (Some(&accounts.token_record_account.to_account_info())),
                delegate: (&accounts.war_enlisting_account.to_account_info()),
                metadata: (&accounts.metadata_account.to_account_info()),
                master_edition: (Some(&accounts.master_edition.to_account_info())),
                token_record: (Some(&accounts.token_record_account.to_account_info())),
                mint: (&accounts.mint_account.to_account_info()),
                token: (&accounts.ata.to_account_info()),
                authority: (&accounts.signer.to_account_info()),
                payer: (&accounts.signer.to_account_info()),
                system_program: (&accounts.system_program.to_account_info()),
                sysvar_instructions: (&accounts.ixs.to_account_info()),
                spl_token_program: (Some(&accounts.token_program.to_account_info())),
                authorization_rules_program: (Some(&accounts.auth_rules_program.to_account_info())),
                authorization_rules: (Some(&accounts.rule_set_account.to_account_info())) 
            },
            DelegateUtilityV1InstructionArgs{
                amount: 1,
                authorization_data: None,
            }
        ).invoke_signed(pda_signers)?;
```